# Display a specific list item in a list view if the array bound to it is empty

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I have a ListView that is bound to a collection:

```
    <ListView  row="1" items="{{ measurements }}" id="measurement-list" loaded="" itemTap="">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <GridLayout columns="5,*,10,*" rows="*, *" class="measurement-item">
            <Label class="{{'severity-' + TrendArrow}}" col="0" rowSpan="2"  text="" />
            <Label class="measurement-value" col="1" text="{{ValueInMgPerDl}}" />
            <Label class="measurement-uom"   col="1" row="1" text="mg/dl"/>
            <Label class="measurement-time"  col="3" text="{{Timestamp}}"/>                
            </GridLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate> 
    </ListView>
```

I would like to display the following if the {{connections}} length is 0

```
<Label col="1" text="No Measuremenets Available" textWrap="false" />
```

others wise I want to display the item.Template above. How can I do this? Everything I've tried so far has failed. The view model has a boolean `hasMeasurement` property but fails when I try to do below in the XML, any guidance? The UI ends up just displaying [object object ] in each table item.

```
<ListView  row="1" items="{{ measurements }}" id="measurement-list">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <GridLayout columns="5,*,10,*" rows="*, *" class="measurement-item" visibility="{{ hasMeasurement ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">
        <Label class="{{'severity-' + TrendArrow}}" col="0" rowSpan="2"  text="" />
        <Label class="measurement-value" col="1" text="{{ValueInMgPerDl}}" />
        <Label class="measurement-uom"   col="1" row="1" text="mg/dl"/>
        <Label class="measurement-time"  col="3" text="{{Timestamp}}"/>                
        </GridLayout>
        <GridLayout rows="" columns="" visibility="{{ hasMeasurement ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" >
            <Label text="No Measurements Available" textWrap="false" />                    
        </GridLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate> 
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, depending on what the main container is, in this case a GridLayout:

```
<Label row="1" text="No Measuremenets Available" textWrap="false" visibility="{{ measurements.length, measurements.length === 0 ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" />

<ListView  row="1" items="{{ measurements }}" id="measurement-list" loaded="" itemTap="" visibility="{{ measurements.length, measurements.length === 0 ? 'collapsed' : 'visible' }}" >
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <GridLayout columns="5,*,10,*" rows="*, *" class="measurement-item">
        <Label class="{{'severity-' + TrendArrow}}" col="0" rowSpan="2"  text="" />
        <Label class="measurement-value" col="1" text="{{ValueInMgPerDl}}" />
        <Label class="measurement-uom"   col="1" row="1" text="mg/dl"/>
        <Label class="measurement-time"  col="3" text="{{Timestamp}}"/>                
        </GridLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate> 
</ListView>
```

Notice the following line in both label and listview, and how they are "reversed":

```
visibility="{{ measurements.length, measurements.length === 0 ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"
```

Comment: Is there some place in NS documentation that describes the very, very odd syntax of {{ propname, propname test }}?